# gdb - optimized value analysis

Tags: gdb

My CPU is arm.How can I figure out the function parameter value if it's optimized out?

For example:

```
status_t NuPlayer::GenericSource::setDataSource(
        int fd, int64_t offset, int64_t length) {
    resetDataSource();

    mFd = dup(fd);
    mOffset = offset;
    mLength = length;
```

Above function has 3 parameters, when I try to print the second parameter offset, I will get below result:

```
Thread 4 "Binder:15082_3" hit Breakpoint 1, android::NuPlayer::GenericSource::setDataSource (this=0xae63bb40, fd=8, offset=<optimized out>, length=9384436) at frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/nuplayer/GenericSource.cpp:123
123     resetDataSource();
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0xb02aaa80 <android::NuPlayer::GenericSource::setDataSource(int, long long, long long)+12>:  blx 0xb0282454 <_ZN7android8NuPlayer13GenericSource15resetDataSourceEv@plt>
(gdb) n
125     mFd = dup(fd);
(gdb) print offset
$1 = <optimized out>
(gdb) p $eax

$2 = void
(gdb) disassemble /m
Dump of assembler code for function android::NuPlayer::GenericSource::setDataSource(int, long long, long long):
122         int fd, int64_t offset, int64_t length) {
   0xb02aaa74 <+0>: push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
   0xb02aaa76 <+2>: sub sp, #4
   0xb02aaa78 <+4>: mov r4, r3
   0xb02aaa7a <+6>: mov r5, r2
   0xb02aaa7c <+8>: mov r6, r1
   0xb02aaa7e <+10>:    mov r7, r0

123     resetDataSource();
=> 0xb02aaa80 <+12>:    blx 0xb0282454 <_ZN7android8NuPlayer13GenericSource15resetDataSourceEv@plt>

124 
125     mFd = dup(fd);
   0xb02aaa84 <+16>:    mov r0, r6
   0xb02aaa86 <+18>:    blx 0xb027e5d8 <dup@plt>
   0xb02aaa8a <+22>:    ldrd    r2, r1, [sp, #24]
   0xb02aaa8e <+26>:    str.w   r0, [r7, #224]  ; 0xe0
   0xb02aaa92 <+30>:    movs    r0, #0

126     mOffset = offset;
   0xb02aaa94 <+32>:    strd    r5, r4, [r7, #232]  ; 0xe8

127     mLength = length;
   0xb02aaa98 <+36>:    strd    r2, r1, [r7, #240]  ; 0xf0

128 
129     // delay data source creation to prepareAsync() to avoid blocking
130     // the calling thread in setDataSource for any significant time.
131     return OK;
   0xb02aaa9c <+40>:    add sp, #4
   0xb02aaa9e <+42>:    pop {r4, r5, r6, r7, pc}

End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

I guess it's in some register but the result of $eax is void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess it's in some register but the result of $eax is void.

There is no register called `eax` on ARM.

To know which register the parameter is in, you need to know [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention).

Looks like you are using 32-bit ARM. From above link:

```
r0 to r3: used to hold argument values passed to a subroutine
```

So you should do `info registers`, verify that `r0 == 0xae63bb40`, `r1 == 8` and find the `offset` in `r2`.

Comment: One question, offset is int64_t but r2 is 32bit, how can r2 storage a 64bit variable?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like example code has assigned the parameter variable to local variable already, so print that value will be exactly the same as optimized out parameters.

```
mOffset = offset;
mLength = length;
```